# getContext function be null when i make some input

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in react function:

```
function App() {

  const handleChange = event => {
    // let nam = event.target.name
    // let val = event.target.value
    // setValues({ [nam]: val})

  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    category: "",
    saturation: true,
    error: ""
  })

  const filteredIndex = (options, filterFunc, n) => {
    var i=-1, j=0;
    for(;j<options.length && i<n; ++j) {
      i += filterFunc(options[j]);
      if(i==n)
        break;
    }
    return options[j];
 }

 const genFilterFunc = (takenValues) => {
    var takenLookup = {};
    for(var i=0; i < takenValues.length; ++i) {
       takenLookup[takenValues[i]] = 1;
    }
    var filterFunc = function(val) {
      return takenLookup[val] ? 0 : 1;
    };
    return filterFunc;
 }

 const randomColourNotUpOrLeft = (grid, row, col, options, ignoreColour) => {
    var takenlist = [];
    if(row > 0 && grid[row-1][col] != ignoreColour) {
      takenlist.push(grid[row-1][col]);
    }
    if(col > 0 && grid[row][col-1] != ignoreColour) {
      takenlist.push(grid[row][col-1]);
    }
    var filt = genFilterFunc(takenlist);
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(options.length-takenlist.length));
    var randomColour = filteredIndex(options, filt, randomIndex);
    return randomColour;
  }

  const fillGridSpeckled = (grid, options, nullColour) => {
    for(var row=0; row<grid.length; ++row) {
      for(var col=0; col<grid[row].length; ++col) {
        grid[row][col] = randomColourNotUpOrLeft(grid,row,col,options,nullColour);
      }
    }
  }

  function makeGrid(gridrows, gridcols, defaultColour) {
    var newGrid = [];
    for(var row=0; row<gridrows; ++row) {
    var thisRow = [];
    for(var col=0; col<gridcols; ++col) {
    thisRow.push(defaultColour);
    }
    newGrid.push(thisRow);
    }
    return newGrid;
}

function drawGrid(withGrid,tileSize) {
  let ctx;
  var activateDraw = (ref) => {
    ctx = ref.getContext('2d');
    // draw stuff
    for(var row=0; row<withGrid.length; ++row) {
      for(var col=0; col<withGrid[row].length; ++col) {
        ctx.fillStyle = withGrid[row][col];
        ctx.fillRect(row*tileSize, col*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  }

  return <canvas id='gallery' ref={(e) => activateDraw(e)} width='500' height='500' />

}

  const filterGallery = () => {
    var nullColour = 'white'
    var fewOptions = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'white' ];
    var grid = makeGrid(5, 8, nullColour)
    return fillGridSpeckled(grid, fewOptions, nullColour)

  }

  const { category, saturation } = values

  var nullColour = 'white'
  var grid = makeGrid(5, 8, nullColour)
  var fewOptions = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'white' ]; // never less than 3!
  var manyOptions = 'AliceBlue,AntiqueWhite,Aqua,Aquamarine,Azure,Beige,Bisque,Black,BlanchedAlmond,Blue,BlueViolet,Brown,BurlyWood,CadetBlue,Chartreuse,Chocolate,Coral,CornflowerBlue,Cornsilk,Crimson,Cyan,DarkBlue,DarkCyan,DarkGoldenRod,DarkGray,DarkGreen,DarkKhaki,DarkMagenta,DarkOliveGreen,DarkOrange,DarkOrchid,DarkRed,DarkSalmon,DarkSeaGreen,DarkSlateBlue,DarkSlateGray,DarkTurquoise,DarkViolet,DeepPink,DeepSkyBlue,DimGray,DodgerBlue,FireBrick,FloralWhite,ForestGreen,Fuchsia,Gainsboro,GhostWhite,Gold,GoldenRod,Gray,Green,GreenYellow,HoneyDew,HotPink,IndianRed,Indigo,Ivory,Khaki,Lavender,LavenderBlush,LawnGreen,LemonChiffon,LightBlue,LightCoral,LightCyan,LightGoldenRodYellow,LightGray,LightGreen,LightPink,LightSalmon,LightSeaGreen,LightSkyBlue,LightSlateGray,LightSteelBlue,LightYellow,Lime,LimeGreen,Linen,Magenta,Maroon,'.split(",");

  return (
    <div>
      {drawGrid(grid, 50)}
      {fillGridSpeckled(grid, category, nullColour)}
      <div>
        <input type='select' onChange={(val) => setValues({ category: val})} name='category' />
        <input type="checkbox" value={saturation} name="darker" id="darker" onChange={handleChange("saturation")} />
        <label >Darker</label>
        <button onClick={filterGallery()} >
          Click Me 
        </button> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i want make filters to hide/show dynamically those matching only and filtered by "category" input: red, green, yellow, blue, brown, gray, purple, pink, other and by saturation (boolean/checbox: "darker" which can be random for each element). but when i fill some input it will TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When you update the state using hooks, make sure to not just update one property of your state object, but also merge it with your previous state.

**Like this:**

```js
<input type='select' onChange={(val) => setValues(prev => ({ ...prev, category: val}))} name='category' />
```

Also you are calling the `handleChange` function in your onChange. Instead use an arrow function and pass `event` and your data i.e. `saturation`

**handleChange:**

```js
...
const handleChange = (event, name) => {
    let {checked } = event.target;
    setValues(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: checked}))

  };
...

<input type="checkbox" value={saturation} name="darker" id="darker" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "saturation")} />
```